# List of dictionaries where value has two double quoted values

Tags: python, string, dictionary, key

I came up with list of dictionaries as a string. I wanted to convert this string to dictionary but it gives error.

```
data = '{ 
        "address": "Ludwig-Wolf-Straß 1, 75181 Pforzheim Eutingen", 
        "lat": 48.90962790, 
        "lng": 8.74648390, 
        "name": "Psychiatrische Tagesklinik Pforzheim "Alte Mühle"", 
        "path": "appportrait7e29d81c345927b0start", 
        "color" : "yellow", 
        "zIndex": "30",}'
```

After checking it, I found out a value enclosed in double quotes two times.

```
data = { 
    "address": "Ludwig-Wolf-Straß 1, 75181 Pforzheim Eutingen", 
    "lat": 48.90962790, 
    "lng": 8.74648390, 
    "name": "Psychiatrische Tagesklinik Pforzheim "Alte Mühle"", # this value 
    "path": "appportrait7e29d81c345927b0start", 
    "color" : "yellow", 
    "zIndex": "30",}
```

I want to turn "Alte Mühle" into a single quote 'Alte Mühle' or just Alte Mühle. I tried to parse the dictionary to str and use string.replace() function but it didn't work. Since the value is dynamic I can't just change the value in a static way. i,e

```
string.replace('"Alte Mühle"', 'Alte Mühle') # will only change this value
```

is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Value is dynamic or the same? You hint at both.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is your input or starting point? The initial dict shown is a syntax error, you cannot operate on it at all.

Comment: The value can be anything. If I only change "Alte Mühle" next time it may return something else.

Comment: Do your string values actually contain start and end double-quotes, or are they delimiters for the string literals? The way you've written it does not make sense either way.

Comment: If you have one double quoted string in a full string then just change the outer quotation to a single one. The code would be "'"+str[1:-1]+"'", where the str is the full string.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it will make sense now

Comment: "next time it may return something else" *What* returns these? Are they some JSON response from an API? The proper fix is likely to fix the source of the data, not the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment, so I'm assuming you are starting with a bunch of string literals you typed manually into your code. If not, there are other ways to handle this or it may have not been an issue to start with.

Here is an solution that doesn't require manually searching for problem strings. Enclose your dictionary string literal using tripple quotes (either `"""` or `'''` are permitted) instead of the single `'` or `"`. This will prevent the interpreter from getting confused about `'` or `"` inside a string literal.

```
data = """{ 
        "address": "Ludwig-Wolf-Straß 1, 75181 Pforzheim Eutingen", 
        "lat": 48.90962790, 
        "lng": 8.74648390, 
        "name": "Psychiatrische Tagesklinik Pforzheim "Alte Mühle"", 
        "path": "appportrait7e29d81c345927b0start", 
        "color" : "yellow", 
        "zIndex": "30",}"""
```

Next, the double quote problem can be handled using regular expressions (`re`). I have to leave this as an exercise as I am on a phone, but you can replace all `"` that lies inside a dictionary value regular expression search string `": \"([.]+?)\",”` with `'`. Find this pattern,  modify the substring, then replace the old substring with the corrected one.

Finally, to interpret it as a dictionary, call `ast.literal_eval(...)` on the corrected string (a version of `eval(...)` made safer by only interpreting literals). Requires the standard library `ast` import.

Consider comparing this workload vs manually fixing your strings or loading the  strings or key/value pairs from a database, avoiding these string literal issues all together.